# Collapsible Tree rendered issue

Tags: json, d3.js

I am trying to render Collapsible Tree from below link but i am not able to render collapsible tree

```
http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/4339083
```

below is my code and json data.i could n't able to figure out where i made mistake.please help

**json data**

```
{
 "name": "flare",
 "children": [
  {
   "name": "analytics",
   "children": [
    {
     "name": "cluster",
     "children": [
      {"name": "AgglomerativeCluster", "size": 3938},
      {"name": "CommunityStructure", "size": 3812},
      {"name": "HierarchicalCluster", "size": 6714},
      {"name": "MergeEdge", "size": 743}
     ]
    },
    {
     "name": "graph",
     "children": [
      {"name": "BetweennessCentrality", "size": 3534},
      {"name": "LinkDistance", "size": 5731},
      {"name": "MaxFlowMinCut", "size": 7840},
      {"name": "ShortestPaths", "size": 5914},
      {"name": "SpanningTree", "size": 3416}
     ]
    },
    {
     "name": "optimization",
     "children": [
      {"name": "AspectRatioBanker", "size": 7074}
     ]
    }
   ]
  }
```

my code:same code i am using in my application only json path is changed

```
var margin = { top: 20, right: 120, bottom: 20, left: 120 },
    width = 360 - margin.right - margin.left,
    height = 200 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

        var i = 0,
    duration = 750,
    root;

        var tree = d3.layout.tree()
    .size([height, width]);

        var diagonal = d3.svg.diagonal()
    .projection(function (d) { return [d.y, d.x]; });

        var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
    .attr("width", width + margin.right + margin.left)
    .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
  .append("g")
    .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

        d3.json("/Js/flare.json", function (error, flare) {

            root = flare;
            root.x0 = height / 2;
            root.y0 = 0;

            function collapse(d) {
                if (d.children) {

                    d._children = d.children;
                    d._children.forEach(collapse);
                    d.children = null;
                }
            }

            root.children.forEach(collapse);
            update(root);
        });

        d3.select(self.frameElement).style("height", "800px");

        function update(source) {

            // Compute the new tree layout.
            var nodes = tree.nodes(root).reverse(),
      links = tree.links(nodes);

            // Normalize for fixed-depth.
            nodes.forEach(function (d) { d.y = d.depth * 180; });

            // Update the nodes…
            var node = svg.selectAll("g.node")
      .data(nodes, function (d) { return d.id || (d.id = ++i); });

            // Enter any new nodes at the parent's previous position.
            var nodeEnter = node.enter().append("g")
      .attr("class", "node")
      .attr("transform", function (d) { return "translate(" + source.y0 + "," + source.x0 + ")"; })
      .on("click", click);

            nodeEnter.append("circle")
      .attr("r", 1e-6)
      .style("fill", function (d) { return d._children ? "lightsteelblue" : "#fff"; });

            nodeEnter.append("text")
      .attr("x", function (d) { return d.children || d._children ? -10 : 10; })
      .attr("dy", ".35em")
      .attr("text-anchor", function (d) { return d.children || d._children ? "end" : "start"; })
      .text(function (d) { return d.name; })
      .style("fill-opacity", 1e-6);

            // Transition nodes to their new position.
            var nodeUpdate = node.transition()
      .duration(duration)
      .attr("transform", function (d) { return "translate(" + d.y + "," + d.x + ")"; });

            nodeUpdate.select("circle")
      .attr("r", 4.5)
      .style("fill", function (d) { return d._children ? "lightsteelblue" : "#fff"; });

            nodeUpdate.select("text")
      .style("fill-opacity", 1);

            // Transition exiting nodes to the parent's new position.
            var nodeExit = node.exit().transition()
      .duration(duration)
      .attr("transform", function (d) { return "translate(" + source.y + "," + source.x + ")"; })
      .remove();

            nodeExit.select("circle")
      .attr("r", 1e-6);

            nodeExit.select("text")
      .style("fill-opacity", 1e-6);

            // Update the links…
            var link = svg.selectAll("path.link")
      .data(links, function (d) { return d.target.id; });

            // Enter any new links at the parent's previous position.
            link.enter().insert("path", "g")
      .attr("class", "link")
      .attr("d", function (d) {
          var o = { x: source.x0, y: source.y0 };
          return diagonal({ source: o, target: o });
      });

            // Transition links to their new position.
            link.transition()
      .duration(duration)
      .attr("d", diagonal);

            // Transition exiting nodes to the parent's new position.
            link.exit().transition()
      .duration(duration)
      .attr("d", function (d) {
          var o = { x: source.x, y: source.y };
          return diagonal({ source: o, target: o });
      })
      .remove();

            // Stash the old positions for transition.
            nodes.forEach(function (d) {
                d.x0 = d.x;
                d.y0 = d.y;
            });
        }

        // Toggle children on click.
        function click(d) {
            if (d.children) {
                d._children = d.children;
                d.children = null;
            } else {
                d.children = d._children;
                d._children = null;
            }
            update(d);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problems were small but pesky ones. Here is the [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/Q8NbR/) with the corrections. You had an extra curly bracket in the end, some missing brackets at the end of the JSON, and finally the width of the graph had to be expanded. Again, small stuff that gets you...

```
width = 800...
```

Comment: thanks for your valuable feedback.now i got your point and issue is resolved